# Radio Button Value: "on"

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have this form, when user clicks on the submit button, a script open a popup where i need to print the radio button value. My problem is the printed value on the popup window: "on" but the result should be a number (selected person's id)

My PHP Code:

```
    <form method="post" action="edit.php" onsubmit="target_popup(this,'edit.php')"><input type="submit" value="Modifica Giocatore"  /><br /><br /><br />
                <?php
                    //my queries (work)
                ?>

                <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    $i=0;
                    while ($i < $num) {
                        $id=mysql_result($results,$i,"ID");
                        $name=mysql_result($results,$i,"Name");
                        $surname=mysql_result($results,$i,"Surname");
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="radioEdit" value"<?= $id; ?>"  /><?= $id; ?></td>
                    <td><?=$name?></td>
                    <td><?=$surname?></td>
                </tr>


                <?php 
                    $i++; 
                    } 
                ?> 

                <?php

                    echo "</table></form>"
                ?>
```

And this is my script:

```
    function target_popup(form,page) 
    {
        window.open(page, 'formpopup', 'left=100,top=100,width=600,height=400,menubar,toolbar,resizable');
        form.target = 'formpopup';
    }
```

edit.php file:

```
    <?php
        $prova = $_POST['radioEdit'];
        echo $prova;        
    ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: So, what's inside `edit.php`?

Comment: I've added it right now @Fred-ii-

Comment: Either the problem is with the PHP not generating the HTML you want, or the HTML not giving the results you want. Whichever it is, you need to be looking at the HTML to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Try `$prova = $id;` instead of `$prova = $_POST['radioEdit'];`

Comment: @Fred-ii- no, it doesn't work

Comment: i think $id is numeric

Comment: Have a look at what I posted below. I couldn't get it to work without using [`sessions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) @Yariet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work was to use [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Here is what I could test without setting up an entire DB.

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
$id="12345"; // test ID number

// works with sessions
$prova = $_POST['radioEdit'] = $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
echo $prova;
?>

<form method="post" action="edit.php" onsubmit="target_popup(this,'edit.php')">
<td><input type="radio" name="radioEdit" value"<?php echo $id; ?>"  /><?= $id; ?></td>
<input type="submit" value="Modifica Giocatore"  />
</form>

<script>
    function target_popup(form,page) 
    {
        window.open(page, 'formpopup', 'left=100,top=100,width=600,height=400,menubar,toolbar,resizable');
        form.target = 'formpopup';
    }
</script>
```

**edit.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['id'];
echo $id;
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_SESSION['id']);
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain me `$prova = $_POST['radioEdit'] = $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
echo $prova;
?>` and `<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['id'];
echo $id;
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_SESSION['id']);
?>` ? Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. It's a `chained` method for variables, where `$prova` is passed on to `$_POST` and so on...@Yariet - I use this method myself. If you test it the way I have it now in a seperate folder, you will see the results.

Comment: Thanks again but i solved using an easier way: editing `<td><input type="radio" name="radioEdit" value"<?= $id; ?>"  /><?= $id; ?></td>` to `<td><?php echo "<input type='radio' name='radioEdit' value='".$id."'/>"?><?= $id; ?></td>`

Comment: You're welcome and am glad to hear you found an easier method :) @Yariet - Thanks for the update, cheers!

Answer (score -1):

What happens when you `echo $id`? Are you sure that it returns a value? Also isn't `<?= ;?>` considered really old and deprecated PHP? You should be using `<?php echo ;?>`

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: A) The first part is an idea for an answer, B) I don't have enough reputation to comment yet...

Comment: `echo $id` gives me a white page. `<?php echo $id;?>` still gives me "on"

Comment: @Yariet it returns `on` when on the form? If yes, then there's something wrong with the query

Comment: if i try to print `$id` next to the radio button the value is right so the query works